# In Corona physics not working for a group of objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a game where eggs with numbers on them drop and there is a basket with number at the bottom. The egg and the number are in a group and added as a physics body. the same for the basket and number. when only the egg is added as a physics body and not the egggroup, then the physics work. The following is my code

```
local physics =require("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(0,9.8)

local egg=display.newImage("egg.jpg")
egg.numberValue=myRandomNumber

 local eggText = display.newText({x = egg.x, y = egg.y, text = tostring(egg.numberValue), fontSize = 30, font = native.systemFontBold }) 

local eggGroup = display.newGroup() 
eggGroup :insert(egg) 
eggGroup :insert(eggText)

physics.addBody(eggGroup , {bounce=0.2})  --if I change to add only egg, then the physics work

-- add basketgroup
local basket=display.newImage("basket.png")
basket.numberValue=math.random(10,20) 
local basketText = display.newText({x = basket.x, y = basket.y, text = tostring(basket.numberValue), fontSize = 30, font = native.systemFontBold })    

local basketGroup = display.newGroup() 
basketGroup :insert(basket) 
basketGroup :insert(basketText)

physics.addBody(basket ,"static")
```

if in the  physics.addBody(eggGroup , {bounce=0.2})  I change to add only egg, then the physics work. Please tell me how to fix this!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of fixing it but the best/easiest one would be:

Add psyhics to egg only.

Change :

```
local eggText = display.newText({x = egg.x, y = egg.y, text = tostring(egg.numberValue), fontSize = 30, font = native.systemFontBold })
```

to (so when multiple object will be there its much easier to retrieve reference to text on egg)

```
egg.eggText = display.newText({x = egg.x, y = egg.y, text = tostring(egg.numberValue), fontSize = 30, font = native.systemFontBold })
```

Then add something like this.

```
local function adjustElements()
egg.eggText.x = egg.x
egg.eggText.y = egg.y
egg.eggText.rotation = egg.rotation
end

 Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", adjustElements )
```

This will add another function that will make text follow Your egg.